# How can I change what user connects to TFS when using TFS power tools 2012 shell extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I have the TFS power tools installed, and I can see the shell extensions context menus; however, I can't find a way to bypass the integrated windows authentication and specify a new username per operation. I am using a common username on a server due to some legacy software, and I need to access TFS with a different domain user. Is there an option to do this on the fly?

I expected to receive a prompt when connecting, but I just get an error indicating that the current user doesn't have permissions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ALWAYS use a certain user name & password when authenticating to a TFS server then you can use Windows Credentials Manager and add a new Windows Authentication entry.  You type in the full server name, domain username, and password.  Additionally, you'll want to add the server name into the "Trusted Sites" list in Internet Explorer.

Just remember to edit that entry in the future if you ever need to change it like when the account's password has been updated.  You'll be pulling out your hair until you remember that it is in there.

Comment: Good to know. It is seeming more like it's not possible to do what I want to do. Thanks for the info though!